# Flutter how i can put custom widget to formtextfield as a suffix?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I have a form textfield and i want to put textbutton as a suffix for i forgot password. But when i try add i cant see anything.

**My Code:**

```
 TextFormField(   
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              suffix:TextButton(child: Text("Şifremi Unuttum?"),onPressed: (){}) 
              ),
              floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: isFocused
                      ? Color.fromARGB(255, 141, 56, 211)
                      : Color.fromARGB(255, 91, 103, 125),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  fontSize: 14),
            ),
          ),
```

When i check suffix wants a widget. So i gave it but its not showing what is the problem in here ? Thanks for helps!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything works for me with your source code. The TextButton is displayed correctly. I will attach the code below, as well as a screenshot, where I added the missing label, because you use styling for it and a condition if you forgot the password, then display a text button in the suffix:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  static bool isFocused = true;
  static bool isForgotPassword = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("App bar"),
        ),
        body: TextFormField(
          initialValue: "My Text",
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            suffix: isForgotPassword ? TextButton(
                child: const Text("Şifremi Unuttum?"), onPressed: () {}) : null,
            label: const Text(
              "Floating Label",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
            ),
            floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(
                color: isFocused
                    ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 141, 56, 211)
                    : const Color.fromARGB(255, 91, 103, 125),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                fontSize: 14),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

[Screenshot of app screen with 2 false booleans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8seo.png)